# List comprehension-like filtering of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a simple array that looks like

```
obj = {1:false, 2:true, 3:true}
```

I would like to retrieve an array of all keys in the object that have a value of true.

In python you can just do

```
>>> [key for key in obj if obj[key]]
[2, 3]
```

Is there a one-line or other simple way of doing this in Javascript? I also have access to lodash.

Comment: `for(var key in obj) if(obj[key]) console.log(key)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in any Ecma5 capable browser using Object.keys and Array.filter:

```
> Object.keys(obj).filter(function(i) {return obj[i]});
> ["2", "3"]
```

Comment: Nice answer, better than mine for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Using new javascript syntax, you can do it like this.

```js
const obj = {1:false, 2:true, 3:true};

const res = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in Firefox 30+.

```
obj = {1:false, 2:true, 3:true};
[for (key of Object.keys(obj)) if (obj[key]) key ];
```

results

```
["2", "3"]
```

Currently, it is the only browser that implements [Array Comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions)

Comment: Really nice, but ECMAscript 7 support is a long journey ;)

Comment: "Non-standard. Do not use!" "Obsolete since Gecko 58 
/ This feature is obsolete."